# "Failed to mount component” error on Laravel 5.3.10 + Vue.js 2.0.1

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js

I have been working on Laravel + Vue.js.
I would like to develop Vue components onto Laravel Blade template,
but when I tried doing that, the following error occured, and it doesn’t work well.
* For the purpose of checking, I have just written only a minimal code of Vue components.

I tried various things in reference to the following articles.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/287

The problem which is occuring and the error message

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in anonymous component - use the "name" option for better debugging messages.)
```

#### index.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import InputText from './components/InputText.vue'

new Vue({
    render(h) {
      return h(InputText)
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### InputText.vue

```
<template>
    <input class="input-text" type="text">
</template>

<script>
export default {
}
</script>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
</style>
```

#### gulp.file.js

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {
    mix.sass('**/*.scss')
       .webpack('')
});
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    bundle: './resources/assets/js/app.js',
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
    },
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.vue?$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'vue-html',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000',
      },
    ],
  },
  vue: {
    loaders: {
      scss: 'style!css!sass',
    },
  },
};
```

#### package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-browsersync-official": "^1.0.0",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.6",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^9.5.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
    ...
}
```

#### complementary information

Laravel 5.3.10
Node.js 6.4.0
npm 3.9.3

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to register the InputText component in order to use it within your root component. Here it is using the ES2015 shorthand.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import InputText from './components/InputText.vue'

new Vue({
    components: {
        InputText
    },

    render(h) {
      return h(InputText)
    }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `esModule: true` next to `loaders` under `vue` in your `webpack.config.js` and you should be good to go.

Alternatively you may use `const Vue = require('vue')` instead of `import Vue from 'vue'` which tries to load the `default` export from the generated module from your component, and it is unable to do so, unless you tell the vue-loader to generate compatible code.

Actually it is a more general incompatibility between the specs, where `export default foo` doesn't mean the same as `module.exports = foo`. When you `require` the former, it will give you an object `{ default: foo }` whereas the latter will return `foo` unencapsulated.

That's why you have to tell vue-loader if you are using either of the specs.