# Vue 2 Failed to mount component

Tags: gulp, webpack, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and Vue 2.0.6. If I use local components, it works fine. But when I try to use global component from another .vue file, it shows following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. (found in component <test> at path\to\site\resources\assets\blog\components\test.vue)
```

**Test.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1 class="hello">Hello</h1>
    </div>
</template>
<style>
    .hello {
        color:blue;
    }
</style>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

**App.js**

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var resource = require('vue-resource');

window.Vue = Vue;

Vue.use(resource);

Vue.component('test', require('../components/test.vue'));

new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official');

var blogResourcePath = './resources/assets/blog';
var blogPublicPath = 'public/blog-assets';

elixir(function(mix) {
        mix.webpack('app.js', blogPublicPath + '/js', blogResourcePath + '/js')
});
```

**Webpack.config.js**

```
'use strict';

const path  = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'resources/assets'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel',
            },
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue',
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: 'style!css'
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
        }
    }
};
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <test></test>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ elixir('blog-assets/js/app.js')}} ">
</html>
```

There is no compilation error. A similar question tis [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910025/failed-to-mount-component-error-on-laravel-5-3-10-vue-js-2-0-1) but that doesn't solve my issues.

Comment: It may be because you registered it as my-component but use it as <test>

Comment: No, rewrite some names to post it on SO. Updating that.

Comment: Am I just missing it or is your mount point not in index.html (#app)

Comment: It was my mistake to put that in the question. It was in the original file.

Comment: did you ever solve this? i can't seem to get past it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this is because with Vue2.0, the default version is the one without template parser. You need to import Vue as follows:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
```

Please check LinusBorg answer here:

https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/topic/4399/vue-2-0-vue-warn-failed-to-mount-component-template-or-render-function-not-defined-found-in-root-instance/6

Comment: I know and according to the installation guide (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build) I added alias in the webpack config (check my webpack.config.js). And it is working as the local components are working. but when it's coming from global components from another .vue file, the error occurs.

Comment: I don't know if the missing `$` could have something to do with it: `'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.js'`

Comment: Added it and compiled but didn't change anything.

Comment: I'm at lost, to be honest. I have the feeling that there must be some of the moving parts failing. Have you tried to build this as a standalone application, without the `laravel-elixir` gulp plugin, and then moving on from there?

Comment: After 2-3 days of trying, I'm also feeling some other things might be wrong. I removed the .vue file and put global component in .js file. That's working but seems not perfect. Anyway, thanks a lot for investigating the issue.